# Serving up pages using Rack (PHP style)

Tags: ruby, rack

How would I go about building a (small?) Rack app that serves Slim templates from say a "views" directory and static files from "static".

I've tried several frameworks that seem to do this, including -- Serve, Brochure, RackServerPages but they all seem to have their own issues.

- Serve won't let you choose a layout
- Brochure bombs on a "yield" in the template
- RackServerPages won't let me pass locals while rendering a partial

Or is there a gem out there that does it already?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I've created apps in Sinatra (and Ramaze and Rails too) but would like to stick with php like pages for my current project

Answer (score 0):

Try [Stasis](http://stasis.me/) - It has layouts, controllers and local variables.